# kubelet Failed to pull image rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Tags: k3s, kubelet

My problem is that afte 2m the pull will stop and it will try again.
I can't pull the image in 2m so I changed the kubelet runtime-request-timeout to 10m but it seems that value is ignored

What I did is [I'm having a k3s cluster]

Edit/create file /etc/rancher/k3s/config.yaml with content:

```
kubelet-arg:
  - "runtime-request-timeout=10m"
```

but this seems to be ignored [restarted all machines]. Am I doing something wrong?

```
│   Type     Reason                      Age                  From               Message                                                                                                                                                    │
│   ----     ------                      ----                 ----               -------                                                                                                                                                    │
│   Normal   Scheduled                   2m32s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/image-f8dq4 to ubuntu2                                                                                                    │
│   Warning  Failed                      33s                  kubelet            Failed to pull image "privaterepo/image:1.0.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded                             │
│   Warning  Failed                      33s                  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull                                                                                                                                        │
│   Normal   BackOff                     33s                  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "privaterepo/image:1.0.0.0"                                                                                       │
│   Warning  Failed                      33s                  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff                                                                                                                                    │
│   Normal   FileSystemResizeSuccessful  32s (x2 over 2m32s)  kubelet            MountVolume.NodeExpandVolume succeeded for volume "pvc-b6152bdd-aef4-4927-929c-674226705ddf" ubuntu2                                                       │
│   Normal   Pulling                     19s (x2 over 2m32s)  kubelet            Pulling image "privaterepo/image:1.0.0.0"
```

LE:
It seems that `runtime-request-timeout` is not for pulls.
Something to mention is that I changed the container runtime from containerd to docker. If I'll leave it as containerd I'll not have this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had not given the proper permission for container. create secret to give permission

```
     image: privaterepo/image:1.0.0.0
 name: queue-manager
 imagePullPolicy: Always
 resources: {}
 imagePullSecrets: 
    - name: mysecret
```

SECRET FILE

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: sdfsdfdsfdsf=
  password: dfsfsdfdsfd
```

Comment: I have a secret created. Is not related with the secret. It will fail right after 2m while it is pulling the image. the problem is that the image is big enough so can't be pulled in 2m. as I said, if I'll use contained as container runtime it will work, if I'll use docker I'll have above error